# Cannot compile the BB10 sample native app "HelloWorldDisplay" in Momentics

Tags: blackberry-10

I'm having trouble compiling the HelloWorldDisplay native appusing the Momentics IDE.
I have followed through the Getting Started guide on the BB10 native SDK developer pages:

https://developer.blackberry.com/native/beta/documentation/getting_started.html

I downloaded the sample apps and attempted to import and build the HelloWorldDisplay app by right clicking it and selecting build.

The build fails and the following console output is displayed:

```
**** Build of configuration Device-Debug for project HelloWorldDisplay ****

make all 
make -j 1 -CDevice-Debug -fmakefile all 
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/pro-cln0042/Downloads/Code/BB10Examples/HelloWorldDisplay/Device-Debug'
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/pro-cln0042/Downloads/Code/BB10Examples/HelloWorldDisplay/Device-Debug'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `HelloWorldDisplay', needed by `all'.    Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2

**** Build Finished ****
```

Was I wrong in thinking that Momentics was supposed to handle this      automatically, and that I should just be able to right-click->build without  settings up any compilers, build files etc?

I'm new to BB development and Eclipse/Momentics in general. Any advice on how to resolve these errors would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your link returns a 404 Not Found error. I suspect you have set up an old development environment. Go to the [BB10 Beta 2 site](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/getting_started/setting_up.html) and download the NDK from there an follow the instructions. The PlayBook and BB10 NDKs are based on Momentics but have substantial customization to support development for BlackBerry (especially BB10). Since it is in Beta it is a moving target and you have to keep your IDE and simulators up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the dead link, fixed. I have version 10.0.6 installed which I think is the latest. Some of the guys on the #BlackBerryDev irc channel had similar problems with different errors. After trying a few samples we were successfully able to build and deploy the "Geolocation" example. Some of the developers suggested that perhaps the samples had not all been updated to be compatible with the latest SDK version. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That is entirely possible. The API is still in flux as they develop the system. It can be frustrating but on the flip side we could wait for the API freeze. One price to pay for early access. The good news is the final API should be complete and available by the end of the month.

Comment: Hi,You can try its new SDK which have version 10.0.9. This version has more functionality then 10.0.6 and some what stable also.

Comment: I am facing same issue, I have 10.0.9 version, is there any new version ?

Comment: The latest version of tools and libraries is 10.0.10.261 but it runs on the IDE delivered with 10.0.9. Select Help->Update Native SDK to get the latest. If you don't have that menu selection uninstall your IDE, download the latest from the developers' site, install it then to the Update Native SDK.